# Excel copy last empty row number to a cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA.

2 worksheets in the same workbook.  I want to get the last empty row number from worksheet 2 and past that number into a cell on worksheet 1.

Anyone, please help.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: @simoco :  But the poster wants the **last empty row** and not the **last used cell.**

Comment: `last empty row` makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`The **last** empty row in a worksheet is usually at or near the bottom the the worksheet.  So we start at the end and work our way up:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For N = Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If wf.CountA(s2.Cells(N, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
        s1.Range("B9").Value = N
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Next N
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To get the first empty row rather than the last empty row, use:

```
Sub qwerty()
        Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
        Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
        Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

        Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

        For N = 1 to Rows.Count
        If wf.CountA(s2.Cells(N, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
            s1.Range("B9").Value = N
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Next N
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  That gives me the last empty row of that worksheet but not the next available empty row.  For example, I want to enter customer information on the next available empty row, sequential order. Sorry if I'm not getting it...

Comment: I think I better clarify further.  This is a database of customers.  Each record is a customer. So, when I have a new customer, I enter that customers information on the next empty row.

Comment: You requested the **LAST** empty row not the **FIRST.** ...................see my **EDIT#1**